# Don't download Messages - Outlook

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I'm setting up MS Outlook. 
I want to start with a blank inbox in my Outlook. I mean I don't want old (last day, week, month) mails to be downloaded from the server. More detailed:  let's say I'm setting up Outlook 2010 now, June 28. On the very first start Outlook will start downloading older mails from the server (June 27, 26, April 3, 1 and so on).

What I want is to have emails starting only from today, June 28th.

How should I do that in MS Outlook 2010?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no setting in Outlook to do that. You could download it all, then set your archive setting to remove everything after a certain date to the archive.pst file.